# QHttpMultiPart upload file boundary issue

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork, qt5.9

I'm trying to upload some files to a server by using `QHttpMultiPart`. The following version file is just an example. For some reason, Qt will automatically add boundary into the files. However, what I truly uploaded are .tar.gz files and they will be considered damaged if such boundary were added.

```cpp
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QNetworkAccessManager *netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
        HTTPFirmwareUpgrader upgrader(netManager,"http://mytest.com");
        upgrader.upgradeCIU();

        return app.exec();
    }

    void HTTPFirmwareUpgrader::upgradeCIU()
    {
        QString filename = "version";
        QString filePath = QString("C:/Users/User/Desktop/HTTP/%1").arg(filename);
        qDebug() << uploadFirmware(filename, filePath);
    }
    
    bool HTTPFirmwareUpgrader::uploadFirmware(const QString &filename, const QString &filePath)
    {
        QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    
        QHttpPart myPart;
        QFile *file = new QFile(filePath);
        if(!file->exists())
            qWarning() << "File DOES NOT exists";
    
        file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        myPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("form-data"));
        myPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"version\"; filename=\"version\""));
        myPart.setBodyDevice(file);
        file->setParent(multiPart);
    
        multiPart->append(ciu);
    
        QByteArray resp = this->post(createUploadRequest(QString("filename=%1").arg(filename)),
                                     multiPart, file);
        qDebug() << "Upload Filrmware " << resp;
    
        return resp != "";
    }

    QByteArray HTTPFirmwareUpgrader::post(QUrl url, QHttpMultiPart *multiPart, QFile *file)
    {
        QNetworkRequest request;
        QEventLoop loop;
        request.setUrl(url);

        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("multipart/form-data"));
        QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager->post(request, multiPart);
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();
        multiPart->setParent(reply);
        reply->deleteLater();

        return reply->readAll();
}
```

This is the original "version" file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfjas.png)

And this is the "version" file that transferred:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkIlP.png)

And if I do not set header for the request, the size of the transferred file will be 0.

Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!!
Turns out I use the wrong way to upload the file. What I need to use is QIODevice instead of QMultipart.